# How to alter ElasticSearch Field name

Tags: elasticsearch

My ElasticSearch mapping created

```
curl -XPUT 'http://myhostname:9200/data/my_data/_mapping' -d '
{
    "my_data" : {
        "properties" : {
                "empID" : {"type" : "integer"},
                "empName" : {"type" : "string"}
        }
    }
}'
```

so, i want to alter fieldname 'empName' to 'Emp_Name'.whether it is possible,and also i had data  existing for this mapping.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I don't think you can alter field names. You'll have to delete your index, create the mapping with the name you want, and re-index your data if possible.